# SELECT every row in Table A for every row in Table B

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, Customer and User. I need to create an output that displays ClientNumber and UserNumber but client number needs to be listed for every clientnumber.

Current tables:

**Customer Table:**

```
CustomerNumber         CustomerName
1000                      Test 1
2000                      Test 2
3000                      Test 3
```

**User Table:**

```
UserName        UserNumber
bgrte            123
hfysd            547
usdfs            654
```

My output is going to look like:

```
ClientNumber     User Number
1000                123
1000                547
1000                654
2000                123
2000                547
2000                654
3000                123
3000                547
3000                654
```

I assume that I am going to need a while loop but I am struggling with figuring out how to make the logic loop through each client number until all user numbers have been added and so on.

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc...) that you are using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use `WHILE` loop, you can use `CROSS JOIN` :

```
select c.ClientNumber, u.UserNumber
from Customer c cross join 
     User u;
```